# How to combine the head of one file with the end of a second file with shell?

Tags: bash

I have two files a and b and want to generate a third file c which has the first three line of a and the last five line of b (preferably with a one-line command).

That's what I got so far, but this only works when I know how long my second file (in this case 10 lines) is:

```
head -n 3 a | cat - b | sed '4,8d'
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just group the commands and redirect its output:

```
(head -3 a; tail -5 b) > c
```

Or even better without invoking a subshell (courtesy of [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams)):

```
{ head -3 a; tail -5 b; } > c
```

You can read about this in [Bash reference manual -> 3.2.4.3 Grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping):

> ```
> ( list )
> ```
>
> Placing a list of commands between parentheses causes a subshell
>   environment to be created (see Command Execution Environment), and
>   each of the commands in list to be executed in that subshell. Since
>   the list is executed in a subshell, variable assignments do not remain
>   in effect after the subshell completes.
>
> ```
> { list; }
> ```
>
> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be
>   executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created. The
>   semicolon (or newline) following list is required.

#### Test

```
$ seq 10 > a
$ seq 20 30 > b
{head -3 a; tail -5 b; } > c
$  cat c
1
2
3
26
27
28
29
30
```

Comment: Although there's no need to invoke a subshell. `{ ... ; } > ...`